# How often is Shift, Control, Alt or Command combined with the secondary click?

Tags: keyboard, expose

One option I have for activating expose is to combined <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd> with a secondary click. I am wondering if any of these combinations are likely to interfere with any useful commands on the Mac. Do any of these combinations already do anything useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen those combos used in a Mac application, and I pay close attention to keyboard/mouse shortcuts. I think you're safe.

Answer (score 1):

Interference depends entirely on the application you are in when you use that combination of keys. Based on my experience, the only applications that get into that deep of a combination of keys (shift+control+cmd+[...]) are very robust like those found in Microsoft Office and the Adobe Creative Suite.